# fopen() does not create file, and fprintf() does not write to existing file

Tags: c

i am writing a simple controll system for a RC-vessel in C, using a PID-controller. I want to write the systems responce to a "results.dat", but when i execute my program the file is not created in my workspace. If i manually create the "results.dat" file nothing is written to it. The rest of the program runs fine.

This is the code:

```
int main(){
    //Phidget declaration
    PhidgetRCServoHandle servo = NULL;
    PhidgetVoltageRatioInputHandle poten = NULL;

    //Variable declaration
    double error, u, dt, relativePostion, filtered_error, position;

    //Files
    FILE *results = fopen("results.dat", "w");
    if (!results){ 
        printf("Could not open file!");
        disconnect(&poten, &servo);
        return 1;
    }

    //Initialize phidgets
    initializePhidgets(&poten, &servo);
    //double length = basinLength(&poten);
    //printf("The basin length is %f\n", length);
    //disconnect(&poten, &servo);
    //return 1;

    //Get setpoint and variables from user
    initializedData v = initializeSystem(&poten);


    //Open files for visualization

    //Time variables
    double elapsed_time = 0;
    clock_t t;
    t = clock();
    //Program loop
    while (elapsed_time < v.t){
        error = getError(&poten, v.abs);
        t = clock() - t;
        dt = (double)(t)/CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
        u = PID_algorithm(error, dt, v.KP, v.KI, v.KD);
        applyThrottle(u, &servo);
        elapsed_time += dt; //total program time since while loop started
        //Print data to console during run: 
        printf("Error %lf \t Time: %f \t Throttle : %lf \n", error, elapsed_time, u);
        position = (v.abs-error-v.aftPos)/LENGTH; 
        fprintf (results , "%f \t %f \t %f \t \n" , elapsed_time , position ,u) ;
    }
    disconnect(&poten, &servo);
    fclose(results);
    system("pause");
    return 1;
}
```

I can't tell what is wrong. I have included the header and googled. I am using visual studio code on a MAC OS.

Comment: It's probably being created in some other directory than where you expect.  It'll be created in the process's current working directory, and what that is will depend on exactly how you run the program, which you haven't described.

Comment: _Side note:_ If you can't open the output file `results.dat`, you're doing a `disconnect`. But, at that point, `poten` and `servo` have _not_ been initialized. So, why do the `disconnect`? That _would_ seem reasonable if you did the `fopen` _after_ doing the `initializePhidgets`

Comment: Make sure that the working directory is writable, and the file system isn't full. Also, you have `printf("Could not open file!");` -- because `printf()` is line buffered, it may not display unless there's a new-line character at the end of the string. Add that, and see if your error message displays.

Comment: It was saved in another directory @NateEldrege, thank you!